# Using Kubernetes and Weave CNI with multiple clusters in the same subnets

Tags: kubernetes, weave

I have a situation where I would like to run two kubernetes clusters in the same AWS VPC sharing subnets. This seems to work okay except the weave CNI plugin seems to discover nodes in the other cluster. These nodes get rejected with  "IP allocation was seeded by different peers" which makes sense. They are different clusters. Is there a way to keep weave from finding machines in alternate clusters. When I do `weave --local status ipam` and `weave --local status targets` I see the expected targets and ipams for each cluster.

Weave pods are in an infinite loop of connecting and rejecting nodes from alternate clusters. This is chewing up cpu and impacting the clusters. If I run `kube-utils` inside a weave pod it returns the correct nodes for each cluster. It seems kubernetes should know what peers are available, can I just have weave use the peers that the cluster knows about.

After further investigation I believe the issue is that I have scaled machines up and down for both clusters. IP addresses were re-used from one cluster to the next in the process. For instance Cluster A scaled down a node. Weave continues to attempt connections to the now lost node. Cluster B scales up and uses the ip that was used originally in Cluster A. Weave finds the node. This then made weave "discover" the other cluster nodes. Once it discovers one node from the other cluster, it discovers all the nodes.

I have upgraded from 2.4.0 to 2.4.1 to see if some fixes related to re-using ips mitigates this issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is a demo [here](https://github.com/weaveworks-experiments/demo-weave-kube-hybrid) where Weave Net is run across multiple clusters. This demo was shown in the keynote for KubeCon 2016.

The most important part is [here](https://github.com/weaveworks-experiments/demo-weave-kube-hybrid/blob/master/weave-kube-join.yaml#L34)
which stops subsequent clusters from forming their own cluster and hence rejecting connections from others.

```
--ipalloc-init=observer
```

It's not a particularly clean solution, hacking around with the config, but it does work.

Comment: So this implies we are using kubernetes federation. Which means that a I have a single control plane across multiple clusters. This is almost the opposite of my situation. I want multiple control planes and thus multiple clusters, but I want them to exist within the same vpc.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested it, but it seems that option `known-peers` should do the trick. Weave host should not try to connect to other hosts when connections to all known hosts is established.

> $ kubectl apply -f "https://cloud.weave.works/k8s/net?k8s-version=$(kubectl version | base64 | tr -d '\n')&known-peers=comma-separated list of hosts. Default: empty."

You can find more information about available options for Weave plugin at the section "Changing Configuration Options":

- [Weaveworks - Integrating Kubernetes via the Addon](https://www.weave.works/docs/net/latest/kubernetes/kube-addon/)

Comment: Not sure this works for me. We are constantly scaling up and down our nodes. So have a fixed set of nodes I don't believe solves the problem. I have updated the question with additional information.

Comment: Taking to account your update, I don't see other option than to separate clusters to different subnets/VPC.